Are the words for "CHING" and "JING" two different words or the same?
Is the Chinese word for Ching and Jing (in the context of Qi Cong) the same in Chinese, or two different words?
I'm comparing two quotes on two different website:
“Ching” simply translates to “book” or “classic text.” Therefore, it denotes the importance of the work within the canon of Taoist literature. Collectively, “Tao Te Ching” could be translated as “The Book of the Way and Its Virtue” or “The Classic of the Way’s Power.”
But a page on a gnostic websie says: The word 精 ching is Chinese, alternately Romanized as jing, tsing, ching, etc), and literally means, "sexual energy, nutritive essence, essence; spirit, sperm, seed; extract; refined, perfected."

The character you're looking for is 经 (traditional character 經). The pinyin romanization is jīng, but the older Wade-Giles romanization is ching1. You can hear an audio recording on wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B6%93#Chinese

道德经 is pronounced "Dàodé Jīng" when written in the romanization method pinyin for Modern Standard Mandarin.  It has a long and rich history, is pronounced in different ways in various dialects, and likely has many ways of being romanized.
What's important is the character here is 经, and in this context it means "classic" or "sacred book" (it has other meanings too).  It's also used in other book titles, like 古兰经 (The Koran) and 圣经 (The Bible).
This is a distinct character from 精 (jīng), which has the same pronunciation as 经 (jīng), but they have no common meanings.  The website you quote seems to give a reasonable list of 精's translations.
